# What is the most efficient way to iterate over jQuery objects

Tags: jquery, performance, for-loop

I have created a simple example on [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/iterate-over-jquery-objects) to help explain my question. In the example on jsperf a style property is set on a link (I am aware that this can be done without a loop).

What would be the most efficient way to **iterate over jQuery objects**?

According to the jsperf results, `.each` performs quite well, but it's also not the fastest. Perhaps there is an even better solution, which I am missing.

1.Example with .each:

```
$('body').find('div.iojo-test-container a').each(function() {
  $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

2.Example with for-loop (slightly faster than .each):

```
var $a = $('body').find('div.iojo-test-container a');
for (var i = $a.length; --i;) {
  $($a[i]).css('color', 'red');
}
```

3.Fastest way of setting style, but **please ignore this case**. It's about the iteration and not setting css-styles.

```
$('body').find('div.iojo-test-container a').css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: are you optimizing out of necessity or just because? Unless `.each()` is giving you heartburn and the site is running extremely slow, don't worry about [preemptive optimization](http://pivotallabs.com/preemptive-optimization/).

Comment: Of course the 2. solution is faster as `each` only adds overhead but using jQuery isn't about finding the fastest solution, apart in the rare cases where you have performances problems. You should worry first about readability and there `each` is the best choice. Client side, you rarely have to worry if a function takes 100 ns instead of 80 ns.

Comment: @dystroy I agree and in the case above I'd go with jQuery's .each.

Comment: @Brad: Thanks for pointing that out. I deleted that comment because I was on another planet when I wrote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**My Humble Opinion**

It's one thing to optimize after you've deployed and maybe just want to fine tune, but unless you *need* to optimize, don't worry about it. `.each()` works fine while also having the added benefit of being readable. (it's clear you're iterating over a collection when `.each` is being called). Not that a `for` loop is less concise, but unless your load times or performance are taking huge hits, don't worry about it at this stage of the game.

If speed was really a concern, jQuery is an *arguably* bloated library. Making calls like `$(this).attr()` over directly accessing `this.attr` can add benefits without sacrificing readability (and avoiding loading up a jQuery wrapper just to set an attribute). However, you've chosen to use the library, so go ahead and use it for now.

Comment: I agree with you on the importance of readability and the danger of micro-optimization. I use jQuery because it hides cross browser issues and makes life generally easier. When I can avoid a library, I will. I'll gladly use native Javascript to solve a case.

Comment: @TJ: don't mis-understand; I use and love jQuery because it's normalizes writing code (understanding i take a slight performance hit because I'm introducing both the overhead of an additional library and most operations I perform come with the expense of an additional wrapper). That being said, it still cuts down on development time and runs _fast enough_ for most needs. And anything that may run slow is more than likely just in need of a refactoring (maybe change work-flow or compartmentalize operations) not in need of being rewritten as "traditional javascript" [sans jQuery].

Comment: [follow-up]. You can still use jquery and reference things like `this.value` over `$(this).val()`; store `var $this = $(this)` if used repeatedly instead of `$(this).css(...); $(this).attr(...); $(this).animate()`. These (and other) optimizations can still make jquery efficient without having to sacrifice the entire library and classify it (as a whole) too slow to execute.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of these fine tuning optimisations. Caching and chaining is important. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('div.iojo-test-container a').css('color', 'red');
```

jquery will iterate by itself all `.iojo-test-container a` and set them your css property

Comment: From the question, when he's talking about approach 3: "but **please ignore this case**. It's about the iteration and not setting css-styles."

Comment: anyway to use `$('body').find('div.iojo-test-container a')` instead of `$(selector)` isn't efficient.

Comment: I found the opposite to be true when testing it using the jsPerf setup in the question - using `.find()` was **more** efficient than your suggested selector.